# mariadb ("mysql") bind not working, empty response

Tags: mysql, bind

I am trying to connect to mysql on host from docker. (from devilbox php - it has socat even without it) in docker I had configured bridge network.
started the docker container, and it works, i can conenct to other ports (on target ips).
when i connect from docker the port is connecting but mariadb does not send anything, empty response. i can just press enters, and nothing happens.
it works when i connect from host to 127.0.0.1

why mysql does not send anything? how to connect  to mysql

Comment: Check the config - is it listening on all addresses or just its localhost ip? Using sockets only? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new user in mysql like below.

```
CREATE USER 'youruser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

in above command '%' mean every source. And try to connect again with above user if it is working mean you need to change user permission at mysql level. May be your user is restricted to localhost host or some specific ip's.